# Why are the middle two rows and leftmost column of a 8 by 8 common anode LED matrix not turning on at all?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, hardware

I am trying to make a LED matrix display a smiling face and then scroll through the numbers 0-9 and the letter A-F. However, when I run the attached code, everything works as it should but the middle two rows and leftmost column when the label on your left does not turn on at all. Is this a hardware issue or something else?

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3B+ and two 74HC595 ICs, one controlling the rows and one controlling the columns.

Thanks

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

LSBFIRST = 1
MSBFIRST = 2
# define the pins connect to 74HC595
dataPin   = 11      # DS Pin of 74HC595(Pin14)
latchPin  = 13      # ST_CP Pin of 74HC595(Pin12)
clockPin = 15       # SH_CP Pin of 74HC595(Pin11)
pic = [0x1c,0x22,0x51,0x45,0x45,0x51,0x22,0x1c]  # data of smiling face
data = [     # data of "0-F"
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, # " "
    0x00, 0x00, 0x3E, 0x41, 0x41, 0x3E, 0x00, 0x00, # "0"
    0x00, 0x00, 0x21, 0x7F, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, # "1"
    0x00, 0x00, 0x23, 0x45, 0x49, 0x31, 0x00, 0x00, # "2"
    0x00, 0x00, 0x22, 0x49, 0x49, 0x36, 0x00, 0x00, # "3"
    0x00, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x32, 0x7F, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, # "4"
    0x00, 0x00, 0x79, 0x49, 0x49, 0x46, 0x00, 0x00, # "5"
    0x00, 0x00, 0x3E, 0x49, 0x49, 0x26, 0x00, 0x00, # "6"
    0x00, 0x00, 0x60, 0x47, 0x48, 0x70, 0x00, 0x00, # "7"
    0x00, 0x00, 0x36, 0x49, 0x49, 0x36, 0x00, 0x00, # "8"
    0x00, 0x00, 0x32, 0x49, 0x49, 0x3E, 0x00, 0x00, # "9"
    0x00, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x44, 0x44, 0x3F, 0x00, 0x00, # "A"
    0x00, 0x00, 0x7F, 0x49, 0x49, 0x36, 0x00, 0x00, # "B"
    0x00, 0x00, 0x3E, 0x41, 0x41, 0x22, 0x00, 0x00, # "C"
    0x00, 0x00, 0x7F, 0x41, 0x41, 0x3E, 0x00, 0x00, # "D"
    0x00, 0x00, 0x7F, 0x49, 0x49, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, # "E"
    0x00, 0x00, 0x7F, 0x48, 0x48, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, # "F"
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, # " "
]
def setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)    # use PHYSICAL GPIO Numbering
    GPIO.setup(dataPin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(latchPin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(clockPin, GPIO.OUT)

def shiftOut(dPin,cPin,order,val):
    for i in range(0,8):
        GPIO.output(cPin,GPIO.LOW);
        if(order == LSBFIRST):
            GPIO.output(dPin,(0x01&(val>>i)==0x01) and GPIO.HIGH or GPIO.LOW)
        elif(order == MSBFIRST):
            GPIO.output(dPin,(0x80&(val<<i)==0x80) and GPIO.HIGH or GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(cPin,GPIO.HIGH);

def loop():
    while True:
        for j in range(0,500): # Repeat enough times to display the smiling face a period of time
            x=0x80
            for i in range(0,8):
                GPIO.output(latchPin,GPIO.LOW)
                shiftOut(dataPin,clockPin,MSBFIRST,pic[i]) #first shift data of line information to first stage 74HC959

                shiftOut(dataPin,clockPin,MSBFIRST,~x) #then shift data of column information to second stage 74HC959
                GPIO.output(latchPin,GPIO.HIGH) # Output data of two stage 74HC595 at the same time
                time.sleep(0.001) # display the next column
                x>>=1
        for k in range(0,len(data)-8): #len(data) total number of "0-F" columns
            for j in range(0,20): # times of repeated displaying LEDMatrix in every frame, the bigger the "j", the longer the display time.
                x=0x80      # Set the column information to start from the first column
                for i in range(k,k+8):
                    GPIO.output(latchPin,GPIO.LOW)
                    shiftOut(dataPin,clockPin,MSBFIRST,data[i])
                    shiftOut(dataPin,clockPin,MSBFIRST,~x)
                    GPIO.output(latchPin,GPIO.HIGH)
                    time.sleep(0.001)
                    x>>=1
def destroy():
    GPIO.cleanup()
if __name__ == '__main__':  # Program entrance
    print ('Program is starting...' )
    setup()
    try:
        loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:   # Press ctrl-c to end the program.
        destroy()
```

Comment: That really sounds like a hardware problem, given that you're doing everything with loops.  There really isn't any place in your code where a mistake would affect only certain rows, or certain columns.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I suspected that this was the problem